# Images appear in simulator but not when uploading to ipod touch (3.0)

Tags: iphone, image, ipod-touch

I created a simple test app with an image (as well as a button with an image) and it runs fine in the simulator.  But when uploading to the iPod, none of the images appear.  The button appears but with no image.

A few things worth mentioning:
  - Today's massive achievement was making it beyond the code signing errors and so I have *not* had any applications uploaded to the device until now.  IOW, it's not a sudden change.
  - The png image is about 100 x 200.
  - I also set an icon image (png 24 x 24) that does *not* appear either.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the capitalization of your filenames--the devices are pickier than the simulator, so if you have a file named foo.png in one place and Foo.png or foo.PNG in another that could be it.

Comment: I wish it were that simple, but the file names match.  In fact, I used the dropdown list to pick the image names within Interface Builder for all except the icon image.  

Is there any "gotcha' having to do with how they are added to the project or something in deployment?  (I believe I used drag and drop, copy option, default, UTF-8 for my settings).

Thanks.

Comment: how are you trying to show your images?  are they just a UIImageView with a pre-set image, or something more complicated?  when you build your app, do you see a step go by in the status bar where it says something starting with "CopyPNG"?  Also, I think the icon image is supposed to be 27x27, not 24x24, but I don't know if that would be enough for it not to show up.  Are the images all in your project directory rather than somewhere else on the disk?

Comment: It seems there are two parts to the problem.  First was that a large number of my png files are apparently corrupt.  After being edited in Picasa and saved as png, they work in simulator but not on the device.

The other part still confuses me that buttons which are added via IB now have images appearing (when I use good files); however, when added programatically, not even the buttons themselves will appear (on the device).  If there is an obvious reason or item to check, feel free to let me know.  For now I'll play with it and repost if no luck.

Thanks for the help David!
-Mike

Comment: I just have had the same problem. Everything is working fine in the simulator but no images appearing on the device. I fixed the capitalization problem (thanks for pointing that out!) I've tried using both jpg and png to see if that was an issue. How did you know your images were corrupt? Did you fix the problem ?

Comment: Also found the following question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090674/iphone-simulator-shows-apps-images-but-iphone-does-not
Doing a full clean worked for me

Comment: My problem was with the upper case and lower case. Man---sometimes Apple is stupid.